# How to create a diverging bar plot that diverges from a non-zero value in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, visualization

Using R, I want to create a horizontal diverging bar plot which diverges from a specified average value. Normally bar plots are diverging from 0, but how can I make a bar plot which diverges from a specified non-zero value?

This is a lollipop chart that displays the intended behavior I am seeking. (Note however is a lollipop chart, not a bar plot)
[Lollipop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJK9t.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way to do this with `dplyr` and `ggplot2`

```r
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>%
  rownames_to_column(var = 'make') %>%
  tibble() %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = mpg - 20, y = fct_reorder(make, mpg), fill = 0 > mpg - 20)) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = seq(10,35,5)) +
  labs(x = 'mpg', y = '', fill = 'flag')
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I am seeking a bar plot with this behaviour, not lollipop plot.

Comment: I've updated the answer to produce a barplot